# В какой момент браузер подгружает шрифты?

Tags: html, css, шрифты, браузер

При верстке я "объявляю" в css-файле все виды и размеры используемого шрифта. К примеру, шрифт `Raleway` содержит 90 файлов `.woff2`. Однако на страницах я обычно использую из этого множества 3-4 шрифта максимум.

**Вопрос**

При объявлении всех шрифтов в подключаемом css-файле - браузер будет пытаться всех их загрузить, или будет загружать их по мере использования в стилях страницы?

Comment: Сколько ссылок вы пропишете в @font-face, столько и подгрузится вариантов начертаний. Если пропишете все 90, браузер будет грузить их все. От дальнейшего использования в стилях это не зависит.

Comment: Спасибо! Придется тогда шрифты выбирать по отдельности.

Comment: На самом деле часто бывает достаточно подключить вообще один вариант типа normal, а жирность регулировать с помощью font-weight - от 100 до 900.

Comment: Тот шрифт, о котором я писал в вопросе, на каждую "жирность" имеет свой файл. Наверное неспроста.

Comment: Я уже сообразил как поступить - загоню в SASS, предварительно все закомментирую, и буду снимать комментарии по мере необходимости использования.

Comment: @humster_spb, первый комментарий - по сути есть ответ на мой вопрос. Но отметить его как решение я не могу, нужен ответ в виде "ответа" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала браузер загружает верстку (html),
Потом шрифты и скрипты, прописанные в теге  по порядку.
Поэтому необходимо подключить css файл со шрифтами раньше остальных стилей.

Если вы используете @font-face, создайте отдельный файл resources.css, пропишите эти @font-face там и вставьте его в верстке выше остальных ваших css файлов.

НО! Почти все шрифты (кроме шрифтов Adobe) есть в интернете и их можно подключить при помощи @import. Например, библиотек шрифтов google fonts при выборе семейства шрифтов и их видов генерирует автоматически @import для вставки. И не нужно прописывать woff, woff2, eot, ttf и другие. Все сделает за вас и сделает проект "легче".

Comment: Спасибо. Но это если сайт расположен в интернете, или в сети с выходом в интернет.

Comment: Да, верно. Если компьютер имеет выход в интернет, то импорт сработает. Без него ничего не призойдет, так как запрос просто не уйдет